# Why is Page_Load not firing after coming back from another page using ASP.NET - ergo epic embarrassment :)

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, response.redirect

Let's say I have two pages on the same ASP.NET C# WebSite.

- Page1.aspx does things in the Page_Load event
- I navigate to Page2.aspx using the menu
- Page2.aspx does some things then **Response.Redirect** back to Page1.aspx
- Page1.aspx cannot do things in Page_Load event this time because it never fires.

I tried to turn off cache declaratively, tried using true for endResponse in my redirect... nothing seems to make a difference.

**Never mind everybody! I am a moron!
Using Visual Studio Dev Localhost the Redirect was redirecting to the live page! :)**

Comment: How are you redirecting?

Comment: Have you tried Server.Transfer? For it or Response.Redirect, you can pass an optional second parameter that's a boolean for whether to send the form variables to the called page. Fiddling with that might yield a difference.

Comment: Is there any code in the page being called? How about OnInit?

Comment: Run Fiddler and check whether a request is being sent at all.

Comment: Yep. It also shows Pragma: no-cache

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for the page executing doesn't affect the page cycle, the Load event *always* fires when the page is executed.

So, if the Page_Load doesn't run sometimes, it's because the page is cached and doesn't execute on the server. The page can be cached in the browser, in a router somewhere along the way, or on the server using server side page caching.

If you haven't enabled server side page caching for the page, it's cached in the browser or in the network. You can use cache settings to try to elliminate this:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

This will keep the page from being cached in normal circumstances. (Check also that your browser isn't in offline mode, then it will use anything in the cache regardless of it's cacheability settings.)

Comment: I used <%@ OutputCache Location="None" VaryByParam="None" %> on the page which I believed to have the same effect. However, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I think if it wasn't for my screw up, this would have been the closest answer to soloving this problem so I accept this as the solution. However, thanks all of you for trying to help.

Comment: @G Berdal: Note that preventing the output cache doesn't prevent the page being cached in the browser or in the network.

Comment: This seems to work in IE(8) but has no effect in Chrome or FF.

Comment: @deadcrab: Applying this only fixes the problem from now on, if you already have a page stuck in the cache, you have to purge the cache in that browser.

Comment: Yeah same here.  Chrome or FF works fine, but IE8 caches the page and Page_load or page_init never fires  unless you put this code in.  Thanks!  This has bugged the he!! out of us for a while.

Comment: So, if we have the problem where Page_Load, Page_Init etc. isn't firing, *where* can we put that Response.Cache line of code so that it will run and end the caching problem??

Comment: @EastofNowhere: You can't end the caching problem like that when you already have it. Setting the cacheability can only prevent future caching problems. For an immediate solution you need to change the URL of the page so that the browser can't use the cached version, for example by adding a query string parameter to it.

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what i needed. I added this line of code to my Page_Load method.

Answer (score 5):

When you navigate to a page using the Back button, the page is reloaded from memory, and no request is sent to the server.

You can confirm this using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com).

I'm not sure if this is true in all browsers.

Comment: I am not using back button. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are redirecting, it's possible the client is caching the response.  In order to get past this you might add an extra query parameter that simply holds the time.

This is usually enough to get past most pages caching mechanisms.

Comment: You need to change your browser settings to get rid of caching.  In IE you should have it set to Check For Newer versions "Every time I visit the webpage" or at the very least "Automatically".  The "Never" settings is (pun intended) Never a good idea.

Comment: I turen off cache in IE, no joy. I'm beginning to think this might not be a caching problem...

Answer (score 1):

Try using Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect.

The client will not see the URL change but this may not matter, depending on your requirements

Comment: In this case the Page_Load event fires. However, because I am using UpdatePanels and some reason this ends up in a Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that this works for me: (add this on the Page_Load section)

```
    if (this.Master.Page.Header != null && Session["RELOAD"] == null)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead hh = this.Master.Page.Header;
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta hm = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta();
        hm.Attributes.Add("http-equiv", "Refresh");
        hm.Attributes.Add("content", "3");
        hh.Controls.Add(hm);
    }
```

and then I add Session["RELOAD"] = "1" right after it executes the code I want to run to prevent it from refreshing over and over again. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Changing VS from debug to Release mode worked for me ....

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following code to disable the page cache in firefox.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
```

Apply this in page load of master page.