# How can a breakpoint on Page_Load NOT get hit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a breakpoint set on a page's Page_Load event that never gets hit. There are no warning or messages indicating the breakpoint may never be hit, it just never gets hit even though the page is loaded successfully.

After a successful login, the user is redirected to this page using the login control's DestinationPageUrl property. As mentioned above, I can login and get to this page so at least that part works.

If I set a breakpoint on the Page_Load event of the Login page (just plain old ASP.NET sample Web Application stuff here), the breakpoint will get hit. I can step into the code but the page_load event never gets hit and the page just appears. In this sequence, I step through the page_load events of the login.aspx and site.master but not the page_load I really want to see.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: your code would probably speak louder than your words

Comment: If you've turned off `AutoEventWireup` for the page, Page_Load won't get called automatically.

Comment: well, its clear its not the postback :P

Comment: I have no problem showing my code but there is nothing to see. It's method headers and that's it. I have some prototype code in the page_load of the page whose breakpoint is not getting hit. This project is based on the ASP.NET Web Application template but, aside from adding the page users are redirected to, there are no changes.

Comment: @bzlm - AutoEventWireup = "True"

Comment: @Special True is the default according to MSDN. No need to include it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple possible answers here:

1. You aren't actually going to the page you think you are.  See [Why is Page_Load not firing after coming back from another page using ASP.NET - ergo epic embarrassment :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281305/why-is-page-load-not-firing-after-coming-back-from-another-page-using-asp-net-e)
2. The browser you are using has aggressively cached the page and isn't loading it.  Make sure your browser of choice has ALL caching disabled.
3. The page is inheriting from a base class which got rid of the onload event.
4. The markup page is inheriting from a class different from the one you expect. (Happens a lot in copy / paste situations.)

Comment: This answer got me thinking about a whole bunch of things. In the end, the page whose page_load would not fire was inheriting from a the wrong page. When I created the page, I dragged and copied an existing page and then renamed it. I didn't take care of all the details in the header of that page's markup. I recreated the page from scratch using a master page, added in the few changes I made, and tested. It worked as expected... except two hours or so later than expected. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 18):

In order for Page_Load to be executed, one of the following must be true:

- You must have AutoEventWireup="true" in the @Page directive of the aspx page.
- The event handler must be wired up explicitly, normally in OnInit

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in @bzlm's comment, the default for AutoEventWireup is "true", so in fact it will be executed also if the AutoEventWireup attribute is missing from the page directive.

Older versions of Visual Studio (2003 certainly, and maybe 2005) used to [explicitly wireup events, and recommend to set AutoEventWireup to false](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814745).

From what I can see, I don't think this is true any more.  The explicit wireup was done with the line:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
```

in the InitializeComponent method that was generated by the designer and called from the `OnInit` method.

Comment: What do you mean, "wired up explicitly" ? Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Not true. "The default value is true if AutoEventWireup is not specified in the @ Page directive" according to MSDN. :)

Comment: i face the same issue and found that I putted AutoEventWireup="false" , I change to true and now working like a charm

Answer (score 8):

if you have  AutoEventWireup="false" in your <% @Page %> directive the Page_Load method will not be attached to the Page.Load event.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the debugging symbols (*.pdb files) for that particular Page_Load event haven't been built.

Try cleaning your solution and ensure that you are in debug mode, then make a simple change to your web.config file (a new line will do) to force ASP.NET to recompile.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but it's still not hitting the breakpoint.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. One final thing you can try (don't laugh!), is to restart Visual Studio. VS can be a little odd at times with debugging and a restart fixes it. Following that, I don't have any more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I had this behavior in a VB web app.

The `Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` did not have a `Handles` after it. I added `Handles Me.Load` and that worked with `AutoEventWireup="false"`.

Setting `AutoEventWireup="true"` also worked as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but none of the answers here helped me. I understand many problems may give this same issue. So i'm giving my solution for when others have the same problem i had. I knew i could set AutoEventWireup to true. I wanted to know how to make it work when AutoEventWireup is false .. in C#. I knew in VB i can just add the 'Handles' clause.

A picture is worth a thousand words, and so is example code, so here's my code snippet:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) // i added this method.
    {
        Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // code for the Page Load event here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add an answer here for what was causing me to experience this problem. It's one of those "oh duh" moments, but it had me stuck for longer than I'd like to admit...

I have a custom base page called `BasePage.cs` which inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`, just like a standard `[Whatever]Page.cs` does. The `OnLoad()` method in `BasePage.cs` does some custom checking and validation. Nothing out of the ordinary here.

My problem was that I was forgetting to call `base.OnLoad(e);` from inside one of my logical checks inside `OnLoad()`. Instead of this I was simply calling `return;`. This was causing the `Page_Load()` method of the actual page file I was trying to view to not be hit. So I changed my code to call `base.OnLoad(e);` inside my check and *boom*, `Page_Load()` was called as expected.

Moral of the story: I'm fessing up to my *dumb*, in the hopes it will help someone else down the road :-).

Comment: Thank you. I also had inherited classes. The problem was that ReSharper was calling these base.x(e) methods redundant and I removed it thinking I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible that the VS may be buggy at that time (it's happened for me) but I never get that consistently.

You mentioned a redirect; if the Redirect happens during Page Init, the Load event would never be called if the request ended.  That could be one reason.

HTH.

Comment: Well, I'm new to web forms development so is this technically a redirect? I'm using the built-in login control and when the user logs in successfully, he is redirected to the page whose page_load never gets hit.

Comment: Oh, OK, wasn't sure where the redirect was happening...  Instead of Page_Load, try doing protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e).  Leave the base.OnLoad(..) statement and put your code/breakpoint here.  See if that runs.  Also, try putting a Response.Write("Here") and see if Here appears on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Changing VS from debug to Release mode worked for me .... Dont aware of reason why its worked , any one expert might suggest

Answer (score 0):

Solution pretty simple in my case.
Check the Page Directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1_Delete.WebForm1" %>
```

The issue with my code was missing the **codebehind** & **inherits attributes.**

Answer (score 0):

As dumb as it is, posting in case it saves someone a minute or two.  I had VS in Release...once I changed it to Debug it fired as expected.  Couldn't figure it out for a bit came back to it, saw it and smacked my head....